# In rsyslog, how to add TAG to message by condition?

Tags: rsyslog

i wish to add a tag to rsyslog message by condition. For example, if message contains the string "ids-alerts" then add to it the tag "MYTAG". Expected to the message to appear in the logger as I've set the logged it with `logger -t MYTAG`

Example expected result in `/var/log/syslog`

```
Jan 14 10:09:08 Syslog-1 MYTAG: 2377448470.246576346 MX84 ids-alerts signature=119:15:1 priority=2 timestamp=1377448470.238064
```